# Не работает функция insert_to_array(которая вставляет число в массив и двигает остальные вперед)

Tags: c

Хорошо так скажем, я пробовал написать функцию которая вставляет в массив определенное число на определенную позицию, но не понимаю почему после вставки числа все остальные числа после вставленного числа обращаются в нуль. Вот мой код, и скриншот компиляции.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100

void insert_to_array (int pos, int x, int n, int score[]);
int main()
{
 int score[N]={10,20,30,40,50},x,n=10,j,pos;

 int i,count = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", score[i]);
    printf(" Initial array \n");

 insert_to_array(pos,x,j,score);
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", score[i]);
    printf("\n");
 return 0;
}


void insert_to_array (int pos, int x, int j, int score[]) {
    pos=5;
    x=88;
    j=10;
    int i;
    for (i = j; i >= pos; i--) {
        score[i] = score[i + 1];
    }

    score[pos - 1] = x;
}
```

[image: Вот скриншот компиляции]

Comment: По логике, при вставке элемента, все, что справа - должно сдвигаться вправо. А Вы, почему-то, сдвигаете, если я не ошибаюсь, влево. А поскольку идете с конца массива к месту вставки, то во все изменяемые элементы записываете значение последнего элемента.

Comment: `score[i + 1]` -> `score[i - 1]`